# Open documents from library in edit mode, just in intranet. How to open externally?

Tags: document-library, permissions

Good evening.

I have a document library, with some Word documents.

I am trying to open the documents in Edit Mode, but I only have sucess when I'm on local intranet.

What is happening? And how to solve it?

Comment: what happens when you try to open document outside local intranet does it gives you any kind of error ?

Comment: @TimeToShine It only opens in Read-only mode.